# Typescript promise bind angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, closures, strict-mode

I am having a problem that my promise isn't being bound to the correct this.

I have read many articles on this subject and I think I understand the problem, but the solution isn't clear.

Suggestions

Here is the code:

```
    // AngleCouch.ts`enter code here`
    namespace AngleCouchDb {

    //Note this is not a ng Service
    export class AngleCouch {

...

    public getAllUsers(): ng.IPromise<any> {
        let dbUrl: string = this.urlPrefix + "/_users/_all_docs?                       include_docs=true";
        let status = new CouchStatus();
        console.log("in getAllUsers");
        return this.http.get(dbUrl);
    }
...
    }
  }

// UserManagementController.ts
module app {
    class UserManagementController {
        static $inject = [
            '$mdSidenav', '$mdToast', '$mdDialog',
            '$mdMedia', '$mdBottomSheet', '$state'];
...

    public fetchUsers = () => {
        let aUser = AngleCouchDb.ActiveUser.getInstance();
        if (aUser.loginStatus `enter code here`!== Shows.StaticData.LoggedIn) {
            return;
        }
        console.log("userManagementController: ");
        console.log(this.$state);

        this.vm.couch = new AngleCouchDb.AngleCouch();
        this.vm.version = {};
        this.vm.docTypeList = [];
        this.vm.couch.urlPrefix = Shows.StaticData.server;

        this.vm.user = new AngleCouchDb.UserCred();
        this.vm.couch = new AngleCouchDb.AngleCouch();
        this.vm.couch.getAllUsers().then(this.getAllUsersCB, (response: any) => {
            console.log(response);`enter code here`
        });
    }
    public getAllUsersCB = (response) => {
            this.vm.gridObj = this.vm.initGridOpt();
            this.vm.gridObj.data = response.data.rows;
    }
...
    angular.module("app").
        controller("app.userManagementController", UserManagementController     );
}
```

Comment: where does it fail?

Comment: During the getAllUsersCB has window as this instead of the instance of UserManagementController.

Comment: That's weird as your `getAllUsersCB` is defined using the fat arrow notation, which should preserve the scope. Is this the exact code you're using or you've changed it before posting it?

Comment: yep, just cut and pasted the code in.  Some code was deleted for shortening the post.  I have also tried making it anonymous fat arrow function.  Same results.

Comment: What happens if you do `...then(this.getAllUsersCB.bind(this), ....` ?

Comment: I get the error: angular.js:13294 TypeError: Bind must be called on a function

Comment: Ummm, ok, try using a normal function for `getAllUsersCB`: `public getAllUsersCB(response) { ...` and keep the `bind` part, what's it doing then?

Comment: That did it!  Had the syntax wrong, so bind may(should) work for ts methods.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: FYI it sounds like you are not running in strict mode. Fix that at once by adding the `"use strict";` directive prologue to the top of every file. Having `this` bound to `window` in unbound callbacks is a serious source of bugs and general insanity.